# PyQt How would i mute a qwebview application?

Tags: html, qt, video, pyqt

My application is a simple html5 video playing application. And i would like to mute the application using a button. But i can't find any documentation

Comment: What are you using to play the video?

Comment: It's just a webview that loads the iframe containg the video player.

Comment: will you be putting the mute button in the code loaded in the iframe, or will it be a button in the container app that needs to trigger the mute action within the code on the webpage (and do you control that code or is it something you cannot change)?

Comment: I am looking for something that would not involve modifying the html through javascript.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with QtWebKit's QWebView as far as I know. You should switch to [QtWebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html) (it's successor) instead, which has a [QWebEnginePage::audioMuted](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#audioMuted-prop) property.

Answer (score -1):

Hello A muted video: The muted attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that the audio output of the video should be muted.

```
 <video controls muted>
```